# Update a table using the fields of the other two table, please help me in this

Tags: sql

My requirement is to update the description field in table 1 with the description of the table 2 and 3 by concatinating. I'll give you the structure below.

table1 --P A D                 table2  ---  P  D              table3 ---   A   D

table D with concatinating The table2 D and table3 D

Comment: Prem, it seems you have *four* questions, including this one, on the *same problem* you are facing.

(1): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204701/update-table-with-a-subquery-which-is-returning-more-than-one-row
(2): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199733/getting-extra-rows-after-joing-the-3-tables-using-left-join
(3): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198183/update-a-table-using-the-fields-of-the-other-two-table-please-help-me-in-this
(4): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204563/updating-row-with-subquery-returning-multiple-rows

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Description)
    SELECT CONCAT(t2.Description, t3.Description) FROM Table2 t2, Table3 t3
    ---- optional join here
```