# Updating Row with Subquery Returning Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting an error while updating the table with a subquery which should not have more than one value, but does.

The query:

```
UPDATE @Table1 SET D = t2.D + t3.D 
FROM @Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN @Table2 t2 ON 
    t1.P = t2.P 
INNER JOIN @Table3 t3 ON 
    t1.A = t3.A
```

Comment: Writing the exact query may help understand your problem and provide alternative solutions.

Comment: Can you please provide at least your platform? The fixes for this will vary by that fairly significantly.

Comment: Please tell us what DB and give us snippet of code to work with ..

Comment: UPDATE @Table1
SET D = t2.D + t3.D
FROM    @Table1 t1 INNER JOIN   
        @Table2 t2 ON t1.P = t2.P INNER JOIN  
        @Table3 t3 ON t1.A = t3.A

I am using oracle....

Comment: befor updating the table i have tried with the subquery what its is returning but when i update using the subquery its throwing error

Comment: Can't tell if your subquery is wrong from the information provided. If it has more than one row but shouldn't, remove the offending rows ;-)

Comment: @Vinay is it possibe to update a table with more rows using a subquery, can you please give a sample code on that.

Comment: Prem, it seems you have *four* questions, including this one, on the *same problem* you are facing.

(1): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204701/update-table-with-a-subquery-which-is-returning-more-than-one-row
(2): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199733/getting-extra-rows-after-joing-the-3-tables-using-left-join
(3): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198183/update-a-table-using-the-fields-of-the-other-two-table-please-help-me-in-this
(4): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204563/updating-row-with-subquery-returning-multiple-rows

Answer (score 2):

On Oracle you can enclose queries that return only one row (scalar subqueries) in parenthesis and use them as you would use variables/columns:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
SET D = (SELECT t2.D + t3.D 
         FROM Table2 t2
             ,Table3 t3
         WHERE t1.P = t2.P 
           AND t1.A = t3.A);
```

If the subquery returns more than one row you probably want to use SUM() in subquery.
Edit: If you do not join tables in subquery, you should probably use two subqueries instead.

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
SET D = (SELECT sum(t2.D) 
         FROM Table2 t2
         WHERE t1.P = t2.P)
        +
        (SELECT sum(t3.D)
         FROM Table3 t3
         WHEREt1.A = t3.A)
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the use of sum?

Comment: SUM guarantees that you will get exactly one row.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Oracle, but I know in SQL-Server you can't pass table names as parameters unless you're willing to dynamically build a SQL string and EXEC() it.

Hopefully an Oracle user can confirm if Oracle can do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the alias for @Table1 in the UPDATE clause - that might even be your problem. Like this:

```
UPDATE t1 SET D = t2.D + t3.D 
FROM @Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN @Table2 t2 ON 
    t1.P = t2.P 
INNER JOIN @Table3 t3 ON 
    t1.A = t3.A
```

This will be much more stable, as it will realise that you're not considering it a separate table in the FROM clause.

In fact, it's really good practice to only use aliases in the UPDATE clause when you have a FROM clause as well.

Rob