# SQL: Updating a field with a sub-query

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm trying to change all the values I have in one column (string) in my table to all lowercase letters. I've tried this statement:

```
update LoanerHeader t1 set Requester = (select LOWER(Requester) from LoanerHeader t2 where t2.ISO_ID = t1.ISO_ID)
```

But am getting the following error: `Incorrect syntax near 't1'.`

I don't really understand why this isn't working, because the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204563/updating-row-with-subquery-returning-multiple-rows) following question has similar syntax. Can anyone help me out? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a subquery. You can just do:

```
UPDATE LoanerHeader SET Requester = LOWER(Requester);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update LoanerHeader t1 
set t1.Requester = (
select LOWER(t2.Requester) from LoanerHeader t2 
where t2.ISO_ID = t1.ISO_ID)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**