# Update table with a subquery which is returning more than one row

Tags: sql

```
SELECT (b.descr || ' - ' || c.descr) description
FROM table1 a
    INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.account = b.account
    INNER JOIN table3 c ON a.product = c.product
WHERE a.descr = ' ' ;
```

How to update a table using the above subquery? its returning more than one row nearly 8000 rows? If you have any solutions for this please share with me?

Comment: Please post the create table scripts - it saves us all time.

Comment: Prem, it seem you have *four* questions, including this one, on the *same problem* you are facing.

1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199733/getting-extra-rows-after-joing-the-3-tables-using-left-join
2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198183/update-a-table-using-the-fields-of-the-other-two-table-please-help-me-in-this
3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204563/updating-row-with-subquery-returning-multiple-rows

Comment: Also, please make take some time out to read the StackOverflow FAQ. (3 comments i know - be better next time!)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you exactly want to do, but you can use the subquery in a subselect statement :

```
UPDATE table1 a SET a.descr = (
    SELECT MAX(b.descr || ' - ' || c.descr)
    FROM table2 b, table3 c
    WHERE b.account = a.account AND c.product = a.product
)
WHERE a.descr = ' '
```

The MAX() will just choose a value for you. If you want to choose it yourself, either restrict the subquery further

Comment: @ steve  i want to update the table1 field descr by concatinating the description of the  table2 and table 3, i got in using the select statement. When i try to update it, it showing the error sub query returning more than one row . Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

In both Oracle & SQL Sever, if sub query return more than 1 row, database will report error.

In your case, if sub query resulted values is same, simply use MAX() or MIN() function to let DB select a value.

Comment: i want to update a table with different values in different row, if we use max() it will update with the same value right. If i am wrong correct me. Help me in finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UPDATE a SET descr = (b.descr || ' - ' || c.descr)
FROM table1 a
    INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.account = b.account
    INNER JOIN table3 c ON a.product = c.product
WHERE a.descr = ' ' ;
```

Where there are multiple rows, table1 will end up with the last one seen.

Rob